# Android transparent DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialog fragment which is shown when the WidgetConfig activity is running. The dialog shows a list of which the user can choose some items. I want this dialog to be transparent so that you can see the home screen in the background of the dialog. This is what I currently do inside WidgetConfig activity:

```
    DialogFragment dialog = new myChooserDialog();  
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));        
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

EDIT: The code of myChooserDialog:

```
public class MyChooserDialog extends DialogFragment{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        choices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.city_choices);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());       
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.widget_dialog_chooser_title));
        builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.widget_dialog_chooser_posBtn), this);
        builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.widget_dialog_chooser_negBtn), this);   
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(choices, -1, this);
        return builder.create();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:   
            //doing magic tricks
            break;

        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;

        default:
            //more magic
            break;
        }   
    }
}
```

Currently, the background is all black. What am I doing wrong here?

Marcus

Comment: You can customize your Dialogs in full. Even DialogFragments. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 15):

Add below lines to your `onCreateDialog`

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color
            .TRANSPARENT));
    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

write below code in your style.xml file.

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
       <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
       <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
       <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
   </style>
```

Set the style to your dialog in your `MyChooserDialog()` class.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    choices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.city_choices);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme.Transparent);
```

Comment: Nope, because I'm not building my dialog in the onCreate method.

Comment: Also, this gives an error: The method getWindow() is undefined for the type DialogFragment

Comment: Also, android.R.style.Theme.Transparent gives this error: The primitive type int of android.R.style.Theme does not have a field Transparent

It's supposed to be R.style.Theme_Transparent

And this gives a white background for my dialog

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your `DialogFragment`

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

Comment: The method getWindow() is undefined for the type myChooserDialog

Comment: `dialog.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));`
Add this instead of `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));  `

Comment: The method setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable) is undefined for the type DialogFragment. Please atleast try the code before you try to post the answer.

Comment: `dialog.getView().setBackground(new ColorDrawable(0));` Try this

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet:

```
getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

Comment: This will affect the entire window. That is, for example, if you want to have a margin between the dialog and window, it won't be visible, so the entire window will be transparent.